# Find all substings_indexes in one table-cell

Tags: mysql, substring

I have in one field a long string with html code for my website.
Total of 29 entries are there but for example in one entry I have 40 prices that contains for example `<td>100 CHF</td>` in middle of this entry.

I can filter the price out with.

```
SELECT substring_index( substring_index( description, '<td>', -1 ) , 'CHF', 1 )
FROM j4xpq_spsimpleportfolio_items
```

My problem is that I get only one result per entry.
So I get 29 prices and **not over 1000** prices.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you are trying to write an HTML parser SQL. It might be a !!fun!! experience but certainly not a wise thing to if you just want to get the job done. If I were you, I'd use an existing HTML parsing library and a language more suitable for this job (javascript, php, python, java, C# etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answere. I undestand all what you want to say to me but this ist a joomla plugin that makes this shit :D i have this over 1000 prices and must to calculate all of this.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The HTML is stored in the database. So far so good. But what exactly prevents you from writing a php script that would fetch 29 entries from the database (there are librarians for doing it for all major programming languages), parse them and do whatever you wanted to do  (e.g. store them back in the database as a 1000 entries)?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>270,00 CHF</td>
    <td>351,00 CHF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>465,75 CHF</td>
    <td>607,50 CHF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>222,75 CHF</td>
    <td>297,00 CHF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>256,50 CHF</td>
    <td>330,75 CHF</td>
</tr>
```

this is the code in one string
I try to get only the prices and calculate.

My calculation is:

270 / 1,35 / 1,19 * 1,4